# Не работает .click() в интерфейсе Gmail

Tags: chrome-extension, gmail, click

Пишу расширение для Chrome. Нужно сделать клик через javascript по кнопке Pop out Reply. Она находится в раскрывающемся меню при написании ответа на письмо. Само меню .click() распознаёт и открывается программно. А кнопка - нет. 
Пробовал с mousedown и mouseup. Пробовал и на чистом javascript, без jQwery. Пробовал применять .click() и остальные триггеры к двум div'ам (внутреннему и внешнему). Программно не нажимается.

```
let reply =  $('div[role="menuitem"]').find('div:contains("Pop out reply")').parent();
     reply.trigger('mousedown')
     reply.trigger('mouseup');
     reply.click();
```

[image: Код кнопки]